# Functions using global variables as inputs

Tags: python-2.7, function, dictionary, global-variables

So, I'm writing some python scripts and I have some code like the one shown below:

```
a = 3
dict = {"run":runMiles(a)}
a = 5
```

The runMiles func takes one variable that is an int. For some reason when dict["run"] is called, the variable doesn't seem to use the "new" variable. It is important to realize that both a and dict are global variables

Comment: The dictionary is not actually called dict it is just an example. I know that dict is a keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does so because the function `runMiles()` executes at the time this line `dict = {"run":runMiles(a)}` executes and when you call `dict["run"]` it will only give the return value got after execution of the function and does not execute the function again to fetch the value of `"run"` and thus the value does not get updated.